# Unexpected token @DragDropContext in react-dnd

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to add `react-dnd` to my project and I have a an error with the annotation `@DragDropContext`.
this is the error:

> ./src/components/card.js
>   Syntax error: Unexpected token (6:4)
>
> ```
>  @DragDropContext(HTML5Backend)
> ```

and here is my code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { DragDropContext } from 'react-dnd'
import HTML5Backend from 'react-dnd-html5-backend'

@DragDropContext(HTML5Backend)

export default class Pane extends Component {
    render() {
       return (
        <h1>test draggable</h1> 
       )
    }
}
```

I also added `"babel-plugin-transform-decorators": "^6.24.1"` and `"babel-plugin-transform-decorators-legacy": "^1.3.4"` to **devDependencies** in package.json and still same error.

I really don't know what else I can do in order to fix this.